# Expression not evaluated to function in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, nosql

I am new to couchDB and tried this from a tutorial

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc._attachments){
        var filename;
        foreach(var key in doc._attachments){

            if(doc._attachments.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof(key) !== 'function')
            {
                filename=key;
                break;
            }
        }
        emit(doc,filename);
    }
}
```

Trying to file name being attached in the database. Its throwing the Expression not evaluated to function error. Can anyone please help to progress in my learning?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly undrestood, you are looking for a design doc which prints all the attachment names. The following code should work.

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc._attachments){
        for(var filename in doc._attachments){
            emit(doc._id,filename)
        };
    }
}
```